# if (getcomponent<Interface>()) returns an error. if(getcomponent<Class>()) works fine. whats the difference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity I am using the OnTriggerEnter function.
trying an if statement to see if I have collided with an object using collider.gameobject.getcomponent<>();
if the component is a class it works fine, if the component is an interface it returns the error "cannot implicitly convert type interactable to bool"(interactable is the Interface name). Fairly new to programming and curious as to why this is an issue?

//error code, the highlighted error is the if statement line. interactable is an interface

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>())

    {
        Interactable interactable = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        interactable.CheckEffect(ability);
    }
}
```

//working code, enemy is a class

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>())
    {
        Enemy enemy = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Enemy>();

        if (enemy.need == objectType)
        {
            DoAction(enemy);
            enemy.AddEffect(this);
        }    }
}
```

Comment: Did you define the Enemy class with an implicit conversion to bool? Interfaces cannot have these conversions. I suspect what you want to do is check if the Interactable component is not null.

Comment: No I havn't done anything like that with the Enemy class, it's just an abstract class with a bunch of variables and methods. I changed the above code to if(coll.gameobject.GetComponent<Interactable>() != null) and it works fine. Just unsure as to why it doesn't work the other way? It's technically the same thing right? unless I'm missing something which i'm sure I probably am as a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every class that inherits from UnityEngine.Object has null checking overriden, which means `if(component)` means `if (component != null)` or `if (gameobject)`  means `if(gameobject!= null)`, and this is because unity also checks for the underlying C++ object pointer that represents the C# facade. But your interface doesn't inherit from `UnityEngine.Object` (after all its an interface), so `if(yourinterface)` doesn't make sense to unity's compiler, to save yourself the trouble and keep consistency across your app/game always do if(x != null) regardless of whether it's a `UnityEngine.Object` object or not.

Answer (score 0):

With accordance with [unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html), unity object overloads operator “bool”. The three examples give the same result (it often using with `GetComponent()`)

1. `if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == true)`
2. `if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())`
3. `if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)`

Interface is not derived from object class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).